# (Ruby) Is there a function to easily find the first number in a string?

Tags: ruby, string

For example, if I typed "ds.35bdg56" the function would return 35. Is there a pre-made function for something like that or do I need to iterate through the string, find the first number and see how long it goes and then return that?

Comment: What should 'ds.-35bdg56' resolve to? Or can that just not happen...

Comment: should resolve to 35 (no negatives)

Comment: Integers only, or should decimal points be supported (i.e. should "ab3.5cd" return 3 or 3.5?)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
>>  'ds.35bdg56'[/\d+/]
=> "35"
```

Or, since you did ask for a function...

```
$ irb
>> def f x; x[/\d+/] end
=> nil
>> f 'ds.35bdg56'
=> "35"
```

You could really have some fun with this:

```
>> class String; def firstNumber; self[/\d+/]; end; end
=> nil
>> 'ds.35bdg56'.firstNumber
=> "35"
```

Comment: This works, but it involves way more human typing and computer processing than necessary. Much easier to pluck out the thing you want than to replace all the stuff you don't want!

Answer (score 6):

```
text = "ds.35bdg56"
x = /\d+/.match(text)
puts x #will return 35 (i hope this helps)
```

Comment: Cleaner than the other solutions. If you want it as an integer, then you'll need `/\d+/.match(text)[0].to_i`.

Comment: or if you want a string, add `.to_s`. As is, it returns a *MatchData* object.

Comment: x will be the string `"35"`  if you want the integer value, try `x.to_i`

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself first, if you are unsure about your knowledge. Half true knowledge does not aid anybody.

Comment: Updated. I was unsure about my reply because I'm new at ruby (and at programming) but of course I tried it out before posting :)

Answer (score 5):

```
text[/\d+/].to_i
```